# Gradle TestNG how to run all suites without hardcoding them in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, testng

I am working on a Java TestNG project with gradle
We have multiple xml test suites
In order to run them we pass them as this :

```
            suites ("src/test/resources/sanity.xml",
                    "src/test/resources/buyside.xml",
                    "src/test/resources/useraccess.xml",
                    "src/test/resources/outboundfiles.xml",
                    "src/test/resources/quicksight.xml")
```

But everytime I add a new suite to the project I have to add it manually in the build.gradle file
Is there a way to get all the suites in the project?

I searched the documentation for gradle-testng and found a method getSuiteXmlFiles() but i dont know how to use it. If I pass it like

```
suites  (getSuiteXmlFiles())
```

It does not work.

Is this the correct method to use and how can I use it ? Or if there is another way to fetch all the suites in the project please let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to do it
I defined a list of all xml files in the folder resources

```
def allSuites = new File("src/test/resources/").listFiles();
```

Then I passed it to the suites method:

```
suites allSuites
```